# Spirit Qi parsing issue with simple C-style structured input

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to setup a basic parser for some game data that uses a familiar and very simple "C-style" format.  Basically, naming braced "structs" then putting parameters and nested "structs" inside.  It would parse something like this:

```
Name0
{
 Name1
 {
  Param0 *= 2
  Param2 = "lol"
 }
 Param0 = 1
 Param1 = "test"

 Name2 { }
}

Name3 {
 Param0 = "test"
}
```

However, it is failing on even the simple input test of "Test {}", much less getting to something as advanced as my above example.  The structs are setup to use fusion, and that seems straight-forward enough that I doubt it is the issue.  I'm not using a couple rules currently, and most of my rules are untested because it fails when it tries the first `category` rule in `root`.  This is the error I'm getting when I input "Test {}":

```
Error! Expecting <sequence>"{"<node> here: ""
```

Here's the Parser class:

```
 template<typename Iterator>
 struct Parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<Category>(), ascii::space_type>
 {
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<Category>(), ascii::space_type> root;

  qi::rule<Iterator, Category(), ascii::space_type> category;
  qi::rule<Iterator, Param(), ascii::space_type> param;

  qi::rule<Iterator, Node(), ascii::space_type> node;

  qi::rule<Iterator, Value(), ascii::space_type> value;

  qi::rule<Iterator, char()> escape;
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> quotedstring;
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> normalstring;

  qi::rule<Iterator> comment;
  qi::rule<Iterator> commentblock;

  Parser() : Parser::base_type(root, "root")
  {
   using namespace qi;

   using ascii::char_;

   using phoenix::construct;
   using phoenix::val;

   escape %= '\\' > char_("\\\"");
   quotedstring %= '"' >> *((char_ - '"') | escape) > '"';
   normalstring %= *(char_ - qi::eol);

   comment = "//" >> *(char_ - qi::eol);
   commentblock = "/*" >> *(char_ - "*/") > "*/";

   node %= category | param; //comment? comment block? holding off for now

   value %= normalstring | float_;

   param %=
    lexeme[+(char_ - operators)]
    > operators
    > value
    > qi::eol;

   category %=
    lexeme[+(char_ - '{')] //won't this grab all whitespace around the tag too?
    > '{'
    >> *node
    > '}';

    root %= *category;

    root.name("root");

    category.name("category");
    param.name("param");

    node.name("node");

    value.name("value");

    escape.name("escape");
    quotedstring.name("quotedstring");
    normalstring.name("normalstring");

    comment.name("comment");
    commentblock.name("commentblock");

    debug(root);
    debug(category);
    debug(param);
    debug(node);
    debug(value);
    debug(escape);
    debug(quotedstring);
    debug(normalstring);
    debug(comment);
    debug(commentblock);

    on_error<fail>
     (
     root,
     std::cout
     << val("Error! Expecting ")
     << _4
     << val(" here: \"")
     << construct<std::string>(_3, _2)
     << val("\"")
     << std::endl
     );
  }
 };
```

And an unrelated thing, is it possible to use C++11 lambdas in `on_success` and `on_error` calls?  I looked into the `on_error` function, and it seems to have its parameters templated to the rule type, meaning a lambda would have to be defined for every single rule type (basically every rule).  Is that correct?  It's too bad, those phoenix lambdas are so opaque, I have no idea how to even pull out a line number and put it in a struct.

edit:

Here's the `operators` table:

```
 struct Operators : qi::symbols<char, Operator>
 {
  Operators()
  {
   add
    ("=", Operator::equal)
    ("+=", Operator::plusequal)
    ("-=", Operator::minusequal)
    ("*=", Operator::timesequal)
    ("/=", Operator::divideequal)
    ;
  }
 } operators;
```

Comment: Maybe boost property_tee with info file format is an option for you.

Comment: @MikeM The INFO Parser in Property Tree looks very interesting and is basically what I'm doing now.  My current format isn't the final format, I was thinking of adding more complicated things (haven't really decided how to do them yet), so I'm not sure if the INFO Parser would handle them... So I'm still curious about fixing this, just in case.  But ya, very nice suggestion!  edit: Ah, actually, it doesn't support modifying existing values like with *=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operators` is not given.

I guess your `node` rule eats the closing `}` so the `catagory` rule cannot succeed.

Comment: Ah, so maybe the first `category` rule gets to "Test {", then it enters `node` and attempts another `category` rule... But `category` only ignores the '{' character, so it eats '}' and dies?  `param` doesn't ignore '}' either... Although that gets tricky.  Can you subtract more than one thing off, cause currently I subtract my symbols table off of the `char_` in `param`... If that's even allowed, I haven't had a chance to test it, haha.

Comment: ``rule - (sub1|sub2|sub3)`` subtracts more. Yes, the ``}`` gets eaten and there is nothing left to close the ``category``. Since you use ``>`` you get an exception with ``>>`` the parsing would not succeed.

Comment: Well, that fixed the first problem and nesting categories works!... but then I try `param` and things fail again.  Gonna have to experiment, but there is one odd thing I noticed.  My `node %= category | param;` rule greatly changes its error and the debug output depending on the order (if i put `param` or `category` first).  It seems if `category` is first, it tries to interpret the `node` as a `category` (according to the debug output), and when that fails just gives up and doesn't even investigate using it as a `param`?  Is order supposed to matter?

Comment: Order matters, the rule you write first is used first, but if it fails, the parser goes back and tries the next rule. But if you get an exception, by using ``>``, the parser stops completely.

Comment: Ok, I'm just avoiding `>` since I don't know when it should be used right now.  Using `>>` has gotten me on the right track!  Thanks!

Comment: Well, ``>`` should be used, when you want to give parser errors to the users. With ``>>`` you just see that it could not be parsed, not why.

Comment: Regarding %=: that is shorthand for the semantic action [qi::_val = qi::_1]. That implies that whatever your Value structure is, it must accept either a vector<char> (or std::string) Or a float. Personally I have tackled this in the past by creating an abstract base class with derived classes that contain either one or the other, and your 'value' rule would then have a pointer to the base class as an attribute. Of course you'd need to use BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT for any structure you use as an attribute. Alternatively you could do it with a boost::variant, but I have never tried it.

Comment: Regarding >: just to expand on Mike M's comment - you only use it when you know that the right HAS to follow the left, otherwise it's an error. I have had trouble mixing > and >> in the same rule by the way, my compiler doesn't seem to like it, so I tend to structure my rules so that they use eithe > or >>. Using > is very useful for getting feedback on why a parse fails, and AFAIK your on_error<fail> function will only be invoked where a > fails. In other case, the parse function just returns false which isn't very useful.

Comment: @FatalFlaw Thanks for the advice!  I'm actually using a `variant` (it's what the official qi doc tutorial does), like so: `typedef boost::variant<std::string, float> Value`.  Very useful to try, found toward the bottom of this page: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/mini_xml___asts_.html .  Have to use visitor pattern to access the values, which they do in `mini_xml_printer` in the example mini_xml2.cpp.  Also using `fusion` in some places.  As for `>`, I'm now using it only for closing braces and the like.

Comment: @user173342: Yes, boost::variant seems like the way to go. Blame too many years programming in C :) Only downside is possibly an inefficient use of space if you have a massive stream to parse.